# Two sequential HTTP requests

Tags: frp, elm

Sorry for newbie's question (and for my english) :)

I tries to write the following function:

- the function downloads a content from *URL1* (it's received as argument)
- the function parses this content and extract *URL2*
- the function downloads a content from *URL2*
- the content from *URL2* is a result of this function
- if an error was occured, this function should return Nothing

I know how to execute the HTTP requests.  I have a function to parse the request from *URL1*.  But I don't know how:

- to execute new request with extracted *URL2*
- to ignore second request if *URL2* isn't extracted (or error in *URL1* is occured)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I principle you want something like this:

```
import Maybe
import Http

type Url = String
getContentFromUrl : Maybe Url -> Maybe String
getContentFromUrl url = --your implementation
extractUrlFromContent : Maybe String -> Maybe Url
extractUrlFromContent content = --your implementation
content = getContentFromUrl (Just "http://example.com") 
          |> extractUrlFromContent 
          |> getContentFromUrl
```

Answer (score 1):

Sending an Http means talking to the outside world, which involves `Signal`s in Elm. So the final result from *URL2* will come packed in a `Signal`. As long as you're ok with that, you can use maybe to return the content of in a `Maybe` in a `Signal`. For example:

```
import Maybe
import Http

-- helper functions
isSuccess : Http.Response a -> Bool
isSuccess response = case response of
  Http.Success _ -> True
  _              -> False

responseToMaybe : Http.Response a -> Maybe.Maybe a
responseToMaybe response = case response of
  Http.Success a -> Just a
  _              -> Nothing

parseContentAndExtractUrl : String -> String
parseContentAndExtractUrl = identity -- this still requires your implementation

-- URL1
startUrl : String
startUrl = "www.example.com" -- replace this with your URL1

result1 : Signal (Http.Response String)
result1 = Http.sendGet <| constant startUrl

-- URL2
secondUrl : Signal String
secondUrl = result1
  |> keepIf isSuccess (Http.Success "")
  |> lift (\(Http.Success s) -> s)
  |> lift parseContentAndExtractUrl

result2 : Signal (Maybe String)
result2 = secondUrl
  |> Http.sendGet
  |> lift responseToMaybe
```

Note that there are plans to make all of this easier to work with: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/elm-discuss/BI0D2b-9Fig/discussion